# Jssor slider navigational thumbnail first image is not left alignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jssor

[image]

here is my code,Jssor slider navigational thumbnail first image is not left alignment? How to do it? I want to do 0-index image left align, thumbnail should start from left

```
var transitions = [
    { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }
];

var options = {
    $AutoPlay: false,
    $SlideWidth: 75,
    $SlideHeight: 75,
    $SlideshowOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
        $Transitions: transitions,
        $TransitionsOrder: 1
    },
    $Cols: 5,
    $Loop: 0,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, 1st slide will align to center.

But you can manually set $Align to 0.

```
var options = {
    ...
    $Align: 0,
    ...
};
```